# Can you use CPS to simulate state in a stateless programming language?

Tags: algorithms, functional-programming, continuations

In a language supporting CPS, but no built in global state, we can represent a state based computation using a function. We call this function a state function. Assume the function takes three arguments, `get`, `put`, and `cont`. The intended interpretation of these functions is that `get` takes a continuation, and applies that continuation to some global state. `put` takes a new state and a continuation, changes the state to the new state, and applies `()` to the continuation. `cont` takes an argument, and ends the computation using that argument as the result.

We can define a function `evalAbs` such that for any state function `f`, `evalAbs(tree, state)` evaluates to `(res, state')`, where `tree` is an abstract syntax tree for `f`, `res` is what `f` evaluates to when it is computed with the global state initialized to `state`, and `state'` is the final state of that computation.

To define `evalAbs`, we can use recursion. The procedure for `evalAbs(tree, state)` is

1. Reduce `tree` to head normal form.
2. If this reduction results in `"\get.put.cont.get(cont')"`, return `evalAbs("\get.put.cont.cont'(state)", state)`.
3. If instead this reduction results in `"\get.put.cont.put(state', cont')"`, return `evalAbs("\get.put.cont.cont'(())", state')`.
4. If instead this reduction results in `"\get.put.cont.cont(res)"`, return `(res, state)`.
5. Otherwise, fail.

My question is if can we write an `eval` (itself written in CPS) that takes `f` itself instead of `tree` (i.e. `f` as a black box).

Comment: CPS isn't a feature that a programming language can "support". Perhaps you meant continuations or call-with-current-continuation/shift & reset, in which case there's no reason for continuation passing style.

Comment: As to your question, look at Filinski's thesis(?) "Representing Monads" as well as algebraic effects approaches as used, e.g., by the programming language Eff. Basically, if your language supports delimited continuations, then you can do this. You can model delimited continuations with a Scheme-style `call/cc` and a single piece of mutable state. It's possible that given Scheme-style `call/cc` *and* writing `evalAbs` in continuation-passing style you would also be okay, since you can model delimited continuations via a double-barrelled CPS.

Comment: @DerekElkins What do you mean? Wouldn't it be correct to say that Haskell supports CPS, but HQ9+ does not?

Comment: @DerekElkins "since you can model delimited continuations via a double-barrelled CPS" How do you do that?